# How to use UIactivityindicatorview while downloading an image from a url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app I have implemented a method to download a image from a URL and display it in a TableView cell. The code is working fine but I also need to implement two more functions,

1) a UIActivityIndicator to show that the image is being downloaded.
2) Check whether the image is already downloaded. Download only if the cell is empty.

Here is my code.

```
-(void) downloadImage
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/iphone5-front-back.jpg"];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

    [dCellImageView setImage:image];

    [image release];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL options:NSDataReadingMapped error:&error]. It is a synchronized method. So probably start activityIndicator before sending the message, and check error, then stop activityIndicator. What do you mean by 'cell is empty'? Do you store image in disk or just memory. If former, use NSFileManager to check if file exists.

Comment: Thanks Luiz for quick reply.I am not saving it to the disk. just keeping in the memory.

Comment: then you may use NSDictionary to save the image using filename as key,

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

It'll show an indicator on the left of the status bar. You can also use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) if you like.

And if you want to check whether the image has downloaded already before downloading, you need to store a key in your Core Data or Property List.